# angular2+ create dynamic provider service base on a param

Tags: angular

as the below plunker, i hope to create dynamic provider by useFactory such as 'TestService'. if the param is 'A', then the provider should be 'TestServiceA', if params is 'B', then the provider should be 'TestServiceB'

how to do it? thanks

https://plnkr.co/edit/8JDopoVCmKSPaQxk0iJH?p=preview

```
export class App {
  type: string = 'A';  

  text:string;
  constructor(
    @Inject('TestService') private testService
  ) {
    this.text = this.testService.test();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return a function from the factory,

```
export function testServiceFactory2() {
  return (serviceType) => {
    return serviceType === 'A' 
      ? new TestServiceA()
      : new TestServiceB()
  }
}
```

and use it like this

```
providers: [
  {provide: 'TestService', useFactory: testServiceFactory2}
]


constructor(@Inject('TestService') private testService) {
  // this.text = this.testService.test();
  this.text = this.testService(this.type).test();
}
```

Comment: hi, thanks your answer. it works but i found another problem that if use twice 'this.testService(this.type)' , the testServiceFactory would create two TestServiceA or TestServiceB services. you can see it in my plunker url.

Comment: Interesting, I'll take a look.

Comment: Well, I don't know what to say, really. That was ***your*** factory. I just showed you how to paramatize it. You put a `new()` in the factory, and then you call the factory twice - I don't see any other outcome - of course you get two instances. If you want a singleton, then code a singleton in your factory!